# WMI how to list processes with type as 'App'?

Tags: wmi, wmic

Task Manager has a 'Type' column, there are 'App', 'Background process' and 'Windows process'.

Do you know how to list only 'App' processes using WMI (C++)?

Answer (score 0):

After much research, the key to performing this operation is to filter on the **mainWindowTItle** property

***A process has a main window associated with it only if the process has a graphical interface. If the associated process does not have a main window (so that MainWindowHandle is zero)***

Source
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle?view=netframework-4.7.2

I am not sure if this is available as a WMI call however but you would need to filter on mainWindowTitle that are true. If you can run the below query remotely your mission would be achieved. I.E

In powershell you could run

```
Get-Process |where {$_.mainWindowTItle}
```

[image: WMI running applications taskmanager type app]

There is a WMI example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer) that may be of assistance.